# Magento 2 - Can't install Magento, setup installation process does not even start

Tags: magento2, installation

Trygin to install Magento but the setup wizard only shows this:
[image]

The error logs shows stuff like:

```
2017-01-24 17:25:02 Error   IP  500 GET /setup/index.php/landing-installer HTTP/1.1
2017-01-24 17:25:00 Error   IP  404 GET /setup/pub/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js.map HTTP/1.1
2017-01-24 17:25:00 Error   IP  404 GET /setup/pub/angular-clickout/angular-clickout.min.js.map HTTP/1.1
```

Does my Magento-CE-2_1_3.zip  is missing some files?

Composer is installed and had ran the composer install, says nothing to update

All PHP necessary extensiones are enabled

PHP is running on 7.0.9 on FPM, tried also FastCGI

Memory limit is 2048M

Ran this command to fix permissions:

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R :psacln . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this problem with add "disable-tls": true in composer.json file in the root like this:

```
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true,
    "disable-tls": true
},
```

src: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Can-t-install-Magento2-setup-installation-process-does-not-even/td-p/69944